# Mouse coordinate seems offset while resizing an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

**OBJECTIVE**

I want the top edge of an element to be draggable to resize this element vertically.

**PROBLEM**

After I click on the edge, as soon as the dragging starts, the top edge is immediately transported around 170px down. After this initial problem, I can drag it up or down as normal and let go wherever I wish to.

**HTML**

```js
const leftPanel = document.querySelector('.additional-content-left-panel-container');
const handle = document.querySelector('.resize-handle');

let isResizing = false; // flag to check if resizing is enabled
let initialY; // initial mouse Y-coordinate
let initialTop; // initial top position of the leftPanel
let initialHeight; // initial height of the leftPanel

handle.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
isResizing = true; // start resizing
initialY = event.clientY; // store Y-coordinate of mouse
initialTop = leftPanel.getBoundingClientRect().top; // store initial top position of leftPanel
initialHeight = leftPanel.getBoundingClientRect().height; // store initial height of leftPanel

console.log('MouseDown - initialY:', initialY, ' initialTop:', initialTop, ' initialHeight:', initialHeight);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
isResizing = false; // stop resizing
console.log('MouseUp - Resizing ended');
document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
});
});

function handleMouseMove(event) {
if (isResizing) {
const offsetY = event.clientY - initialY; // how much the mouse has moved
const newTop = initialTop + offsetY; // calculate new top position
const newHeight = initialHeight - offsetY; // calculate new height

console.log('MouseMove - offsetY:', offsetY, ' newTop:', newTop, ' newHeight:', newHeight);

leftPanel.style.top = newTop + 'px'; // apply new top position
leftPanel.style.height = Math.max(newHeight, 0) + 'px'; // apply new height, but not less than 0
}
}
```

```css
 body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      body * {
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px !important;
      }

      .container {
        padding: 10px;
      }

      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        table-layout: auto !important;
        width: 100%;
      }

        .user-info-table {  
            margin-top: 12px;a
            padding: 0 10px 0 22px;
            position: : relative !important
        }
        
        .user-info-table > table > tbody > tr > td {  
            font-size: 16px !important;
        }
        
      td,
      th {
        padding: 10px;
          padding-bottom: 18px;
        text-align: left;
      }

      .full-width-input {
        width: 98%;
        padding: 8px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
          box-sizing: border-box; /* Add this line */
          font-style: italic;
      }
        
        .full-width-input:focus-visible, .large-input:focus-visible {
        outline-color: #666666;
      }

      .large-input {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
          border-radius: 5px;
          box-sizing: border-box; /* Add this line */
      }

      .button-row {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .white-button {
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .white-button:hover {
        border-color: #aaa;
      }

      .icon {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
        filter: grayscale(80%);
      }

      .icon:hover {
        filter: grayscale(0%);
      }

      .section {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .left-side {
        width: 67%;
        margin-top: 16px;
      }

      .right-side {
        width: 33%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 10px;
      }

      .flex-container {
          flex-wrap: wrap;

      }
        
        .admin-buttons-row {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
            width: 100%;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
      }

      .admin-buttons-cell {
          display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center !important;
        justify-content: center !important;
          align-items: flex-start;
      }

      .flex-row {
        display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between; 
      }

      .flex-cell {
           display: flex;
    min-width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
      }

      .field-label {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #333;
      }
        
        .container {
          padding-right: 0px !important;
      }
        
      .user-notes {
          margin-left: 8px !important;
          margin-bottom: 14px;
        text-align: left !important;
        font-style: italic;
          font-size: 16px !important;
        color: #333;
      }

      .button {
          width: 130px;
          height: 36px;
        color: white;
        background-color: var(--strikingly-primary-color);
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 8px 20px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      .button:hover {
        background-color: var(--strikingly-primary-hover-color);
      }

      .split-button {
          width: 130px;
        display: flex;
      }

      .split-button:hover>div {
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
      }

      .main-button {
          width: 130px;
        padding: 8px 20px;
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
        text-align: center !important;
        background-color: var(--strikingly-primary-color);
        color: white;
        font-weight: 600;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .main-button:hover {
        background-color: var(--strikingly-primary-hover-color);
      }

      .arrow-button {
          width: 22px;
        background-color: var(--strikingly-secondary-color);
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
        padding: 8px 4px;
        color: white;
        /* White arrow */
        align-items: center;
        border: none;
        /* No border */
        cursor: pointer;
          height: 100%;
      }

      .arrow-button:hover {
        background-color: var(--strikingly-secondary-hover-color);
      }

      .dropdown-button {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
          top: 3px;
          left: 15px;
        background-color: white;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
        
        .dropdown-content-rightmost {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
          top: 15px;
          left: -130px;
        background-color: white;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }

      .dropdown-content a, .dropdown-content-rightmost a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
      }

      .dropdown-content a:hover, .dropdown-content-rightmost a:hover {
        background-color: #efefef;
          border-radius: 10px;
      }

      .dropdown-button:hover .dropdown-content, .dropdown-button:hover .dropdown-content-rightmost {
        display: block;
          
      }
      .white-button {
          width: 130px;
        padding: 8px 20px;
        border-radius: 5px 5px;
        text-align: center !important;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        font-weight: 600;
        border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
        
        .white-button:hover {
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
            border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
      }

      .white-split-button {
          width: 130px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: stretch;
      }

      .white-main-button {
          width: 130px;
        padding: 8px 20px;
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
        text-align: center !important;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        font-weight: 600;
        border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .white-main-button:hover {
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
      }

      .white-arrow-button {
          width: 22px;
        position: relative;
        left: -1px;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
        padding: 8px 4px;
        color: black;
        /* Black arrow */
        align-items: center;
        border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
        /* #cdcdcd border */
        cursor: pointer;
          height: 100%;
      }

      .white-arrow-button:hover {
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
      }
        
        .icon.thumbs-up, .icon.thumbs-down
        {
            position: relative; top: 0px;  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
        }
        
        .icon.thumbs-up:hover, .icon.thumbs-down:hover
        {
            top: -2px;  transition: top 0.125s ease-in-out;
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }
        
        .additional-content-left-panel {
        }
        
         .last-buttons-row
        {
            margin-bottom: 10px
        }
    
        .additional-content-left-panel-container
        {
            top: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden !important;
            border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
             resize: vertical !important;
            overflow-y: auto !important;
            height: 70%;
            max-height: 80%;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .additional-content-left-panel-container::-webkit-scrollbar 
        {
            width: 14px;
        }
        
        #chats-redesign > div > div.css-9xjip2 > div.css-sn4l67
        {
            height: 30%;
        }
        /* Hide checkboxes */
input.mangoorchard-accordion {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* Flex layout for rows */
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.row .col {
  flex: 1;
}
.row .col:last-child {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

/* Styles for the mangoorchard-accordion container */
.accordions {
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Styles for individual accordions */
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.accordion-label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.accordion-label::after {
  content: "\276F";
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.05s;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.accordion-label:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.accordion-content {
  max-height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  transition: all 0.05s;
}
.accordion-close {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.accordion-close:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

/* Styles for checked state */
input.mangoorchard-accordion:checked + .accordion-label {
  background: #ebecef;
}
input.mangoorchard-accordion:checked + .accordion-label::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
input.mangoorchard-accordion:checked ~ .accordion-content {
  max-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px 0 16px;
}
        
        .admin-panel-container
        {
            padding-left: 2px; width: 100%;
        }
        
.resize-handle {
    cursor: ns-resize;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
}
 #chats-redesign > div > div.css-9xjip2 {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="resize-handle"></div>
    <div class="user-info-table">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="field-label">First, last name</td>
            <td colspan="3">user_name, user_last_name</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="field-label">Plan, status</td>
            <td colspan="3">user_plan, user_plan_status</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="field-label">Method</td>
            <td>payment_method</td>
            <td class="field-label">Last&nbsp;4</td>
            <td>card_4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="field-label" colspan="1">Registered on</td>
            <td colspan="3">registration_date</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="field-label">Reseller</td>
            <td>is_user_reseller</td>
            <td class="field-label">Last chat</td>
            <td>last_chat</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="user-notes">user_notes</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="admin-panel-container">
    <div class="admin-buttons-row">
      <div class="admin-buttons-cell">
        <div class="split-button">
          <button class="main-button">Admin</button>
          <div class="dropdown-button">
            <button class="arrow-button">
              <div style="transform: scaleY(0.5);">&#x25BC;</div>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Profile</a>
              <a href="#">Sites</a>
              <a href="#">Domains</a>
              <a href="#">Emails</a>
              <a href="#">History</a>
              <a href="#">Payments</a>
              <a href="#">Rewards</a>
              <a href="#">Email settings</a>
              <a href="#">Affiliate</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-cell">
        <button class="button">Copy login</button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-cell">
        <div class="split-button">
          <button class="main-button" title="Changes your">Language</button>
          <div class="dropdown-button">
            <button class="arrow-button">
              <div style="transform: scaleY(0.5);">&#x25BC;</div>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content-rightmost">
              <a href="#">English</a>
              <a href="#">Portuguese</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordions">
      <div class="accordion">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chck0" class="mangoorchard-accordion">
        <label class="accordion-label" for="chck0">
          <span></span>Sites </label>
        <div class="accordion-content">
          <div class="user-sites-row">
            <div class="flex-row">
              <div class="flex-cell">
                <div class="white-split-button">
                  <button class="white-main-button">Site</button>
                  <div class="dropdown-button">
                    <button class="white-arrow-button">
                      <div style="transform: scaleY(0.5);">&#x25BC;</div>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                      <a href="#">Editor</a>
                      <a href="#">Live site</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-cell">
                <div class="white-split-button">
                  <button class="white-main-button">Site</button>
                  <div class="dropdown-button">
                    <button class="white-arrow-button">
                      <div style="transform: scaleY(0.5);">&#x25BC;</div>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                      <a href="#">Editor</a>
                      <a href="#">Live site</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-cell">
                <div class="white-split-button">
                  <button class="white-main-button">Site</button>
                  <div class="dropdown-button">
                    <button class="white-arrow-button">
                      <div style="transform: scaleY(0.5);">&#x25BC;</div>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content-rightmost">
                      <a href="#">Editor</a>
                      <a href="#">Live site</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion" style="position: relative; top: -1px;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chck1" class="mangoorchard-accordion">
        <label class="accordion-label" for="chck1">
          <span></span>Domains </label>
        <div class="accordion-content">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <div class="flex-cell">
              <button class="white-button">Domain</button>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-cell">
              <button class="white-button">Domain</button>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-cell">
              <button class="white-button">Domain</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion" style="position: relative; top: 5px;">
      <input type="checkbox" id="chck2" class="mangoorchard-accordion">
      <label class="accordion-label" for="chck2">
        <span></span>Billing </label>
      <div class="accordion-content">
        <div class="flex-row">
          <div class="flex-row last-buttons-row">
            <div class="flex-cell">
              <button class="button">Invoices</button>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-cell">
              <button class="button">Sub history</button>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-cell">
              <button class="button">Recurly</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion" style="position: relative; top: 12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" id="chck3" class="mangoorchard-accordion">
      <label class="accordion-label" for="chck3">
        <span></span>Kodi </label>
      <div class="accordion-content">
        <input style="margin-bottom: 16px;" class="full-width-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter instruction...">
        <div class="button-row">
          <button class="white-button">Templates</button>
          <button class="white-button">Instructions</button>
          <span>
            <a class="icon thumbs-up">
              <a class="icon thumbs-up">
                <img src="C:\Users\Zé\Downloads\25297.png" alt="Thumbs Down" style="padding-left: 10px; transform: scale(0.77); opacity: 0.3;">
              </a>
              <a class="icon thumbs-down">
                <img src="C:\Users\Zé\Downloads\25297.png" alt="Thumbs Down" style="padding-left: 10px; transform: scale(0.77) scaleY(-1); opacity: 0.3;">
              </a>
            </a>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
          <div class="left-side" style="pad">
            <textarea class="large-input" placeholder=""></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="right-side">
            <div class="flex-column" style="margin-top: 20px;">
              <div class="flex-cell">
                <button class="button" title="Copy everything">Copy full</button>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-cell">
                <button class="button" title="Remove greeting">Copy links</button>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-cell">
                <button class="button" title="Find other templates fitting the same description">Find others</button>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-cell">
                <button class="button" title="Send all paragrapsh one by one so as not to overwhelm user">Slow send</button>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-cell">
                <button class="button" title="Depending on settings, removes greeting, template names, brackets, etc.">Clean</button>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-cell">
                <button class="button" title="Translate into the language chosen under the input field.">Translate</button>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-cell">
                <button class="button">Button 6</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the actual HTML file I'm using:

https://easyupload.io/xpudd2

The draggable edge is the one at the top of the table in the left side:

[image]